# Could someone explain this python permutation code?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I've seen some postings of code for permutations on here but I haven't really been able to find a good step-by-step walk through of what is actually going on. If someone could just explain what is actually happening in each step of this code I would really appreciate it. I can't quite seem to wrap my head around it. The code I'm looking at is in Python and is from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/753.

```
def all_perms(str):
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]


for p in all_perms(['a','b','c']):
    print p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the name of the parameter `str` is a bad choice. It's probably due to the fact that it works for all kinds of sequence types in Phyton but it should be `seq` or something to make the intention clear.

1. If the length of the list is <= 1 (empty or one element) return the list (there is just one solution for this case).
2. For all other cases:

   a) Create all permutations of `str[1:]` (i.e. the list just without the head element).

   b) Insert the head element at each position in each permutation created in a) and return the result

`yield` works a bit like `return`; the main difference is that the current value is returned and, when the function is called again, it continues with the instruction after the `yield`.

This way, it's easy to assemble the result.

Example:

`'a'` gives `'a'` (trivial).
`'ab'` first chops of the head (`'a'`), then creates all permutations of `b` (there is just one: `'b'` itself). Now the head is inserted at every position, so we end up with `'ab'` (head+list) and `'ba'` (list+head).

etc.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. The combination of the yield and recursion made it tough for me to grasp at first, but it makes sense now. And I know what you're saying about the str variable. Had I written it I wouldn't have named it that either, but I just grabbed it from the site I mentioned in my original post. Thanks again!

Comment: It's astonishing how much more simple some code can become when you give variables the proper names; that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def all_perms(str):
    # If there is only one item, there can be only one permutation
    # yield the single item
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        # loop over the permutations returned by a recursive call to all_perms
        # note it is passing a subset of the list passed in.
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            # for each returned sub-permutation insert the item that
            # wasn't passed into each possible position.
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]


for p in all_perms(['a','b','c']):
    print p
```

So you pass in `['a','b','c']`.

It calls `all_perms(['b', 'c'])` and that calls `all_perms(['c'])` which yields 'c'.

the `yield` statement means that `all_perms()` is a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) the fact that it calls itself means it is using [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

I'd recommend using [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) rather than that snippet.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I knew about itertools.permutations but I really just wanted to have a better understanding of what was going on in the code I posted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a [iterator generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). It's a function that returns an object which can be looped over.

during the execution of the `for` loop, `all_perms` is executed up to the point where it hits a `yield`. The value `yield`ed is passed to the loop as `p` variable. Then the execution of `all_perms` is continued at the position after the `yield` statement where the method exited last time.